# Login button don't work on IE7,8,9

Tags: javascript, facebook, internet-explorer, authentication

This is my first app. The login button doesn't work on my app. It is displayed, but when I click on it, nothing happens.

```
  <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
  <html xmlns:fb="http://www.facebook.com/2008/fbml" xmlns:og="http://opengraphprotocol.org/schema/">
  ....
  <body>
  <div id="fb-root"></div>
  <script>
        window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
              FB.init({
              appId      : '306025322809511',
              channel    : 'http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/channel.php',
              status     : true, 
              cookie     : true,
              xfbml      : true,
              oauth      : true,
              });
              FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () {
                    if (response.authResponse) {
                          window.location = "/manage.php";
                    }
              });
        };
        (function(d){
        var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk'; if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
        js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
        js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/all.js";
        d.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(js);
        }(document));
  </script>
  ....
  <div class="fb-login-button">Se connecter en utilisant Facebook</div>
```

I have tried with the channel parameter, but the style was not displayed without channel.

Comment: Does anything appear in your console? Press F12 to view the console.

Comment: The console only say "FB is not defined" and if Y run the debugger, I can login.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, the problem is caused by iFrame of apps.facebook.com/koreplayer/, IE don't save the cookie becaused is in a frame. This is a security feature of IE to prevent fraud.

Answer (score 0):

You need a trigger action on "fb-login-button" to call FB.login(). You can do this with onclick() or using jQuery $('.fb-login-button').click( function() { FB.login(); });

Also, the problem below won't provent login for popping up, but it'll stop the refresh after log in. So, if you're already logged in, it would make it look like nothing happens as the login box will just open and then close down because it has nothing to do.

```
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function () { 
                if (response.authResponse) { 
                      window.location = "/manage.php"; 
                } 
          });
```

Need to change to

```
          FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) { 
                if (response.authResponse) { 
                      window.location = "/manage.php"; 
                } 
          });
```

Finally, windows.location should ideally have a full URL (starting with http:// or https://). Doesn't have to, but should to make it work better.

---

Edited after comments below:

```
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '306025322809511',
        channel    : 'http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/channel.php',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
    };
    FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
    if (response.authResponse) {
      window.location = "http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/manage.php";
      }
    });
```

You need to have the FB.Event subscribe inside the fbAsyncInit function:

```
window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
      FB.init({
        appId      : '306025322809511',
        channel    : 'http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/channel.php',
        status     : true, 
        cookie     : true,
        xfbml      : true,
        oauth      : true,
      });
      FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function (response) {
        if (response.authResponse) {
          window.location = "http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/manage.php";
         }
      });
    };
```

---

Late edited: I've added the "response" into the parameters for the auth-subscribe in hte second part of the post.

Comment: Thank but if I keep the FB.Event with your fix, IE make a loop.

Comment: Also, I have lost the style to button, the 'FB' is not defined.

Comment: I use PHP and the JS SDK from facebook, When user go to index.php, and PHP return $userInfo valid, the user go to manage.php page, if in manage.php $userInfo return false, user return to index.php page for login.

Comment: The code work, this issue is only with IE, not in FF, Chrome or other. See the app at http://koreplayer.fb.levelkro.com/

Comment: Added more the the answer above. Not sure that's everything, but progressing - bit by bit :)

Comment: Just to note that my "edit" matches your code sample in the opening question - but the actual HTML returned in the application does NOT match the code in your opening question... so check all your files are consitent, as that may be causing the problem.

Comment: For unknown reason the code work for now in IE, without change. It's very strange ....

Comment: It's all to do with timing. Some events happen "at the same time" and it's luck which one finishes first. You need one to finish before the other, Don't leave to chance - fix the code.

Comment: The problem is always here, for the moment 'response' is not defined.

Comment: I guess you've changed some more code :). I'll check again later!

Comment: I can't test this as your app DOES NOT LET ME LOG OUT even though I'm logged out of facebook. You say you "suivant les consignes de l'API de Facebook" so please follow them and log me out when I log out of facebook. Merci.

Comment: Late edited: I've added the "response" into the parameters for the auth-subscribe in the second part of the post. Then you should have it!

Comment: With function (response) IE make a loop but not login

Comment: I know, I can't logout also of app, for unknown reason.

Answer (score 0):

I use xfbml parse to render my buttons after i know js sdk has loaded, use below.

---

```
<div id="login_button"><div>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>
      window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
        FB.init({
    appId  : '135669679827333',
    status : true, // check login status
    cookie : true, // enable cookies to allow the server to access the session
    xfbml  : true, // parse XFBML
    channelUrl : 'https://anotherfeed.com/emo/channel.html', // channel.html file
    oauth  : true // enable OAuth 2.0
        });  
function loginbutton(){
var loginb=document.getElementById('login_button');
login.innerHTML+='<div class="fb-login-button">Se connecter en utilisant Facebook</div>';
FB.XFBML.parse(loginb);
};
setTimeout("loginbutton();", 2000);
      };
  // Load the SDK Asynchronously
(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1&appId=135669679827333";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

---

NOTE: this will render a login link only.